# Prove the convergence of following (improper) integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am looking for a proof on the convergence of the following integral:
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2+\sqrt{x}} $$

Since for $0<x<1, \sqrt{x} > x$, I've tried comparison test with $ \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2+x} $ which unfortunately diverges. In fact, I feel like the following integral would converge if  $0 < p < 1$:
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2+x^p} $$ but I have no clue how to prove this. Any hints or ideas on the possible approaches would be appreciated.

Comment: $x^2+\sqrt x \geq \sqrt x$

Comment: @copper.hat : Just post that as an answer with a bit of elaboration?

Comment: @copper.hat That lower bound is false, it is the other way around.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Since we are talking about $0<x<1$, I don't think that equation holds.

Comment: Oops, sorry, mea culpa.